# Using HTML forms to set a localSession's variable

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm a **newbie** so excuse me, I'm still learning and wanting to test stuff.

I want to make a registration form for my website. I don't want to have a `handler.php` to handle the data set by the form; instead I want it to be saved as `localStorage` data, so that when a user registers, it isn't saved on my server, but is saved in their `localStorage`.

Is this possible? If it is not, thank you for telling me.

Here's a visual explanation of what I mean:

[image: A visual explanation]

Comment: It's possible, but don't you want to know when someone registers to your site? If not, what's the point of registration anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the use case, but for learning purposes here's how it can be achieved:

```
<script>

    function welcomeUser() {

        // Check if we have a userName stored for this client.
        if(localStorage.getItem("userName")) {

            // Welcome the user if we do!
            alert("Welcome back " + localStorage.getItem("userName"));

        }

    }

    function saveData() {

        // Get input values
        var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
        var email    = document.getElementById('email').value;

        // Save to localStorage    
        localStorage.setItem("userName", userName);
        localStorage.setItem("email", email);

    }

    // Welcome our user.
    welcomeUser();

</script>

<form name="registerForm" action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="saveData()">
  <input type="text" id="userName">
  <input type="email" id="email">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a6t4wgzt/1/

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage

Comment: Thank you so much, that really helped. I was confused about the action of the form. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I'm still new to JavaScript and just wanted to try to make an experimental signup form for a practice project I'm working on. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem buddy, hope you have a nice day :-) @NabilTharwat